# Configure Notepad++ to execute with Processing and display errors from processing

Tags: notepad++, processing

This is the IDE that we are using in my course http://processing.org/
However it's very buggy with my computer and I love to use Notepad++

How can I make it so that when I press execute in Notepad++, it will compile the file in processing automatically and if there's any errors, it will be ported into Notepad++ showing the line with the error and error message?

Comment: Please made a complete post and write it below your question as the answer. Community will approve it and it will become the source of help for many. Try to make it complete in detail note. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

use nppExec plugin for notepad++, install it from
[notepad++: plugins -> plugin manager -> show plugin manager]

[notepad++: plugins -> nppexec -> console output], set both to utf-8 (optional tbh, but I use it for python)

[notepad++: plugins -> nppexec -> execute ]
paste in the following exactly, but change the path at the start of the line to point to your processing directory

"D:\processing-2.0\processing-java.exe" --run --force --sketch="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" --output="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/ouput"

then save it as a macro

[notepad++: plugins -> nppexec -> advanced options ], use the associate script dropdown to add a menu item, with the 'add/modify' button

click the checkbox at the top that says 'place to the macros submenu' (optional probably)

[notepad++: settings -> shortcut mapper]

look in 'plugins' section

you'll find an entry for the menu item you just created, map a key to it (eg alt-f5)

There is a nice language def for syntax highlighting processing on
http://intuitionlogic.com/post/2011/03/15/A-Notepad++-language-definition-file-for-ProcessingProcessingjs.aspx

Save it as  .xml
then use
[language -> Define]

Comment: And if I have Processing in a usb stick?
There's a variable that identify the drive in which notepad++ is?
I don't know, something like `%%~D0` in batch [=

Comment: Ok, I make it, the solution is `%(CURRENT_DRIVE)`!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a plugin for Notepad++ that sends the code to the Processing compiler and does a correct syntax highlighting etc.
If you just want to use Notepad++ because the Processing is crashing for you, you should try to update your installation of the Java Redist as the IDE relies fully on Java.

Comment: I got it working."C:\Computer Science\processing-2.0b4\processing-java.exe" --run --force --sketch="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" --output="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/ouput"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer FLong, it works fine with Notepad++ 6.6.8 and Processing 2.2.1
But one more line to the macro helps a bit. Add `npp_saveall` to the macro, then the files you are working on will save before they are compiled by processing.

Like this:

```
npp_saveall

"D:\Programmering\processing-2.2.1\processing-java.exe" --run --force --sketch="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" --output="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/ouput"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to answer this post after so long, but the script given by FLong works no more on Processing 3.*.

Basically, it wouldn't run the sketch specifying the output path after `--run` have been called...

So, simply the code for NppExec would be `"C:\Folder where you have processing\processing-3.0.1\processing-java.exe" --sketch="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" --output="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/output" --force --run`.

Note that: a) using `--force` it will delete and rewrite the `output` folder and all its content, and b) using an output folder is optional!

Hope it will helps [: